# Save data and send email to the user with their password and email

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developping a Asp.Net MVC 5 project. I have this controller that save data from a user.Now i  wanna sedn an email to that user after i have saved the data notifying him/her with the password we auto-generated.
Here is my create action

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(TeacherViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Create", viewModel);
        }

        var teacher = new Teacher
        {
            Identifier = viewModel.Identifier,
            Name = viewModel.Name,
            Surname = viewModel.Surname,
            Email = viewModel.Email,
            PhoneNumber = viewModel.PhoneNumber,
            Ville = viewModel.Ville,
            Block = viewModel.Block,
            Password = viewModel.Password
        };

        _context.Teachers.Add(teacher);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedireToAction("Index","Home");
```

Comment: You can use `SmtpClient` to send emails. Google "Sending emails with SmtpClient" and you will find a lot of samples.

Comment: How to do that with razor view

Comment: Why do you want to do that in view. Do it in your action method ( or a service being called from this action method) after saving the data to your table.

Comment: Don't send passwords in email, never! Always use https to receive or send data that includes a password or other confidential data.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the tip. Do you mind giving me one example of what you saying? Because I don't get when you say use HTTPS to receive or send data with that includes confidential data

Answer (score 0):

Save data and send email to the user with their password and email

As you need to send an email and password in email after save the data, please refere below mentioned code as per your requirement, Hope it helps you.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(TeacherViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("Create", viewModel);
    }

    var teacher = new Teacher
    {
        Identifier = viewModel.Identifier,
        Name = viewModel.Name,
        Surname = viewModel.Surname,
        Email = viewModel.Email,
        PhoneNumber = viewModel.PhoneNumber,
        Ville = viewModel.Ville,
        Block = viewModel.Block,
        Password = viewModel.Password
    };

    _context.Teachers.Add(teacher);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    // For send an email 
    string mailfrom = "sender mail", mailTo = teacher.Email, //"receiver mail",
            subject = "Subject Line", filepath = "", htmlbody = "";

    filepath = Server.MapPath("~/path_for_email_template/template.html");
    htmlbody = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filepath);
    /*  you can replace some dynamic contents from body as per your requirements like as name, email but for that you need to  all the variable with unique pattern so you can easily replace them, ex: %name% */
    htmlbody = htmlbody.Replace("%name%", teacher.Name)
                .Replace("%password%", teacher.Password)  // as you want to send a password inside mail.
                .Replace("%email%", teacher.Email);

    try
    {
        // you need to include
        // using System.Net;
        // using System.Net.Mail;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("host");
        client.Port = 25;// int port number
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Sender_UserName", "Sender_password");
        client.EnableSsl = false;//true if ssl required

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.To.Add(mailTo);
        msg.From = new MailAddress(mailfrom.Trim());
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.Body = htmlbody;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        client.Send(msg);

    }
    catch (SmtpException ex) { throw (ex); }

    return RedireToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```